# syslog command in C code

Tags: c, syslog

```
#include<syslog.h>
syslog(LOG_INFO, "Start logging");
```

The above syslog command is not logging in the syslog. So I tried,

```
openlog("Logs", "", LOG_USER);
syslog(LOG_INFO, "Start logging");
closelog();
```

This fails to log anything and I get the following error:

```
syslog: unknown facility/priority: 8049584
```

Comment: refer http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/gnu/glibc/html_chapter/libc_18.html

Answer (score 23):

This line is wrong:

```
openlog("vyatta-conntrack", "", LOG_USER);
```

The "" *should* have been an integer:

```
void openlog(const char *ident, int option, int facility);
```

The integer should be any of these constants ORed together:

```
   LOG_CONS       Write directly to system console if there is
                  an error while sending to system logger.

   LOG_NDELAY     Open the connection immediately (normally, the
                  connection is opened when the first message is
                  logged).

   LOG_NOWAIT     Don't wait for child processes that may have
                  been created while logging the message.  (The
                  GNU C library does not create a child process,
                  so this option has no effect on Linux.)

   LOG_ODELAY     The converse of LOG_NDELAY; opening of the
                  connection is delayed until syslog() is
                  called.  (This is the default, and need not be
                  specified.)

   LOG_PERROR     (Not in POSIX.1-2001.)  Print to stderr as
                  well.

   LOG_PID        Include PID with each message.
```

Try again with something more like:

```
openlog("vyatta-conntrack", LOG_PID, LOG_USER);
```

Note that your `syslogd` configuration might not be set up to keep messages of log level `LOG_INFO`. Try `LOG_ALERT` or something for debugging this problem -- if it works, then drop back to `LOG_INFO` and configure your `syslogd` to keep the log messages that you want to keep. Adding a line like:

```
*.* /var/log/all_messages.log
```

will do the job for `rsyslogd(8)`. Be sure to read the `rsyslog.conf(5)` manpage if your system uses `rsyslogd(8)`. If your system uses a different syslog daemon, then check your system's manpages for details.

Answer (score 12):

You really should compile with all warnings enabled and debugging, i.e. `gcc -Wall -g`.

Read again the [openlog man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/openlog). It is declared as:

```
 void openlog(const char *ident, int option, int facility);
```

so passing `""` as the second argument is wrong (and the compiler did warn you about that). It should be e.g. `LOG_PERROR|LOG_PID` or some other flags.

Answer (score 4):

```
openlog("vyatta-conntrack", "", LOG_USER);
```

This line is wrong as your passing string as second parameter. please check man     page, second parameter is of type int.

try this:

```
    #include <syslog.h>
      int main() {
      openlog("Logs", LOG_PID, LOG_USER);
      syslog(LOG_INFO, "Start logging");
      closelog();
    }
```

output:

```
May 20 16:36:19 prabha-VirtualBox Logs[8114]: Start logging
```

Comment: The output will be in /var/log/syslog.

Comment: Not only `/var/log/syslog`, but `/var/log/messages` too